# trouble with deserialize a json string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize json string with a class, but I got this error, please help.

I got this error

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'JsonTest.EmailModels' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
>   deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
>   interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array."

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"[
'insurance':{
    'individual':{
            'registrationID':'',
       'amount':'',
       'Fullname':'',
       'Email':''
    },
    'multi':{
            'borRegistrationID':'111111',
       'amount':'132',
       'paidfor':{
                '2391734':'44',
         '4773998':'44'
       },
       'emailList':{
                '2391734':'jfowler@thepelicangroup.ca',
       '4773998':'edaho.properties@gmail.com'
       }
        }
    }

]";
        EmailModels emailModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailModels>(json);
        foreach (var item in emailModel.insurance.multi.paidFor)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }

    }
}
public class EmailModels
{
    public Insurance insurance { get; set; }
}

public class Insurance
{
    public InsIndividual individual { get; set; }
    public InsMulti multi { get; set; }
}

public class InsIndividual
{
    public string registrationID { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
public class InsMulti
{
    public string borRegistrationID { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> paidFor { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> emailList { get; set; }
}
```

It should display (2391734, 44
                   4773998,44)

Comment: The sample *does not* contain JSON. It has string that looks like JSON but really is not (`['insurance':` can't be valid start of JSON)... Please [edit] to clarify if your question is how to parse string that looks like JSON or something else.

Answer (score 0):

it looks wrong right at the beginning,  the insurance isn't contained within an object

```
[ 'insurance':{
```

should be

```
[ {'insurance':{...}  } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the basic syntax of JSON, you must use `{}` instead of `[]` for `EmailModels` is not an array but an object.